# Nginx no load properly

Tags: nginx

I have a problem when I request de url, the page is not load properly.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream servers {
    server 192.168.13.23:9075;
    server 192.168.13.24:9075;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxyserver;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://servers/servlet/com.openti.total.hlogin;
    }
}
```

the error is 500

[Browser creenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHH1z.png)

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: the error show access denied 404 
Scriptgxfrmutl.js
Scriptgxcallrpc.js
Scriptgxautosuggest.js
Scriptsetevent.js
etc....

Comment: Your question states that the error is 500. but you comment that the error is 404. The first is a server error and the second is simply file not found.